# android adapter stuck in 0 position

Tags: java, android, adapter

i have an imageAdapter
this is the code :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public String[] imagePaths;

    public ImageGalleryAdapter(Context c, String paths) {

        mContext = c;

        imagePaths = paths.split(";");

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagePaths.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return imagePaths[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("IMAGE GALLERY ADAPTER", ""+position);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imagePaths[position]));


        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));

        return imageView;
    }


}
```

i dont know why, but it always make my apps not responding, so i try to set Log.i to check the position in getView, and the result is position always have value = 0, whereas imagePath.length = 4.

why this always stuck in position = 0

This is the log :

```
07-11 18:38:25.310: I/IMAGE GALLERY ADAPTER(32154): **0**

07-11 18:38:25.313: I/MdpService(32154): [MDP INFO](32154): BpMdpService::parseJpg addr:0x53c64000, size:65536, fd:59

07-11 18:38:25.316: I/MdpService(32154): [MDP INFO](32154): BpMdpService::parseJpg reply:6

07-11 18:38:25.316: W/skia(32154): Use JPEG SW Decoder

07-11 18:38:25.484: I/dalvikvm-heap(32154): Grow heap (frag case) to 29.849MB for 19660816-byte allocation

07-11 18:38:25.726: I/SurfaceTextureClient(32154): [void android::SurfaceTextureClient::init()] debug.stc.fps: 3000 ms

07-11 18:38:25.744: E/MMUMapper(32154): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)

07-11 18:38:25.746: I/IMAGE GALLERY ADAPTER(32154): **0**

07-11 18:38:25.749: I/MdpService(32154): [MDP INFO](32154): BpMdpService::parseJpg addr:0x53c64000, size:65536, fd:60

07-11 18:38:25.751: I/MdpService(32154): [MDP INFO](32154): BpMdpService::parseJpg reply:6

07-11 18:38:25.751: W/skia(32154): Use JPEG SW Decoder

07-11 18:38:25.943: I/dalvikvm-heap(32154): Grow heap (frag case) to 48.574MB for 19660816-byte allocation

07-11 18:38:26.191: I/IMAGE GALLERY ADAPTER(32154): **0**

07-11 18:38:26.194: I/MdpService(32154): [MDP INFO](32154): BpMdpService::parseJpg addr:0x53c64000, size:65536, fd:60

07-11 18:38:26.195: I/MdpService(32154): [MDP INFO](32154): BpMdpService::parseJpg reply:6

07-11 18:38:26.195: W/skia(32154): Use JPEG SW Decoder

07-11 18:38:26.214: I/dalvikvm-heap(32154): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 19660816-byte allocation

07-11 18:38:26.243: E/dalvikvm-heap(32154): Out of memory on a 19660816-byte allocation.
```

please help to solve this

Comment: What is the value of `paths`?  Can you step through or log this value and also the size of `imagePaths`.

Comment: You're force closing because of the out of memory error.  Looks like it's trying to allocate 19mb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though your bitmaps are causing an out of memory exeption and not being added, try re-sampling the images to be smaller

```
Out of memory on a 19660816-byte allocation.
```

are you even adding the item to the string array?